Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: There is no file with ID 6. The file list may have changed. Error: There is no file with ID 6
I have this error when I open a modal with two InputFile, then close the modal and then reopen the modal and upload a file in one of the InputFile.
The two InputFile are in two razor components.
This is where the two components are inside the modal code :
<div class="product-portrait-container">
    <div class="product-portrait-image-container">
        <p>@Localize["Product_Background_Image"]</p>

        <div class="product-image-div">
            <ProductImageUploaderComponent @ref="_backgroundImageUploader"
                                            IsPortrait="_isPortrait"
                                            NotifyParent="NotifyProductCreationModal"
                                            AllowedFileExtensions="@Constants.ALLOWED_PRODUCT_IMAGE_FILE_EXTENSIONS"
                                            IsEditMode="@_isEditMode"></ProductImageUploaderComponent>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-portrait-image-container">
        <p>@Localize["Product_Image_Foreground"]</p>

        <div class="product-image-div">
            <ProductImageUploaderComponent @ref="_imageForegroundUploader"
                                           IsPortrait="_isPortrait"
                                           NotifyParent="NotifyProductCreationModal"
                                           AllowedFileExtensions="@allowedImageForegroundFileExtension"
                                           IsEditMode="@_isEditMode"></ProductImageUploaderComponent>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

ProductImageUploaderComponent
<InputFile id="@($"fileInput{ComponentId}")"
            type="file"
            name="file"
            accept="@AllowedFileExtensions"
            style="display: none"
            @ref="InputFile"
            OnChange="UploadImage" />

I tried all the solution proposed on others question, but at no luck so far.
Thanks in advance for any pieces of advice you can provide.

Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64809676/18667225

@Markus Yes, i already tried to warp their solutions around my code, but had no success. How would you do it if it could work? Any ideas ? Thanks
